# Include header file in abstract syntax tree CDT

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree

Problem: I want generate function prototype if it doesn't exists, in the C file, I have done this, but in case if the prototype already exists in a header file it doesn't feel it, BTW I used CDT IIndex

```
//C Code
#include "test.h" //where it have bar prototype
void bar(void)
{
    //function body
}


//Obtaining the AST [JAVA CDT CHECKER]
ITranslationUnit tu = (ITranslationUnit) CDTUITools.getEditorInputCElement(editor.getEditorInput());
String cFilePath = tu.getResource().getFullPath().toString();
ICProject[] allProjects = CoreModel.getDefault().getCModel().getCProjects();
IIndex **index** = CCorePlugin.getIndexManager().getIndex(allProjects);
IASTTranslationUnit ast = null;
try {
    index.acquireReadLock(); // we need a read-lock on the index
    ast = tu.getAST(index, ITranslationUnit.AST_SKIP_INDEXED_HEADERS);
} finally {
    index.releaseReadLock();
    ast = null; // don't use the ast after releasing the read-lock
}


//In the AST visitor class
/**
 * extract prototype and store them into 'prototypes' hash set and then rewrite the AST.
 */
@Override
protected int visit(IASTSimpleDeclaration simpleDeclaration) {
    IASTDeclarator[] declarators = simpleDeclaration.getDeclarators();  
    boolean isProtoFuncDeclaration = false;
    for (IASTDeclarator declarator: declarators) {
        if( declarator instanceof IASTFunctionDeclarator)
        {
            isProtoFuncDeclaration = true;
        }
    }   
    if(isProtoFuncDeclaration)
    {
        prototypes.add(simpleDeclaration);
    }
    return super.visit(simpleDeclaration);
}
```

The output of the new C Code

```
#include "test.h" //where it have bar prototype
void bar(void) <=== I shouldn't be inserted as it is already in the header

void bar(void)
{
    //function body
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

- Traverse the AST to find the `IASTFunctionDefinition` for which you maybe want to add a prototype.
- Use `getDeclarator().getName()` to get the function name,
- Use `IASTName.resolveBinding()` to get the function binding.
- Use `IIndex.findDeclarations(IBinding)` to find all declarations and definitions of the function.
- From the resulting `IIndexName[]`, filter out the definition itself (check `IName.isDefinition()`).
- Further filter the list to declarations that appear in included header files (since `findDeclarations()` will return declarations in the entire project). You can do this by calling `IASTTranslationUnit.getIndexFileSet()` on your AST, and checking `IIndexFileSet.contains(name.getFile())` for every `IIndexName`.
- If after this filtering, the list is empty, you know you need to add a prototype.

Comment: IIndexFileSet indexFileSet = ast.getIndexFileSet(); always be empty ?? so I can not perform if(indexFileSet.contains(funcDeclarations[i].getFile()))

Comment: @MostafaHassan: I don't know why the index file set would be empty. I would expect it to get populated during parsing (inside the `getAST()` call) via `CPreprocessor.executeInclude()` [`case FOUND_IN_INDEX`] -> `CPreprocessor.processInclusionFromIndex()` -> `LocationMap.skippedFile()` -> `ASTTranslationUnit.skippedFile()`. If you're in a position to debug the CDT source, you could check what is going wrong in this sequence of calls.

Comment: boolean prototypeFound = false;
   indexNames = index.findDeclarations(funcBinding);
   for(int i=0;i<indexNames.length;i++) {
    IIndexName indexName = indexNames[i];
    if(!indexName.isDefinition()) { // this is function and has no body(definition), so it is prototype
     IIndexFile indexFile = indexName.getFile();
     if(!ast.getIndexFileSet().contains(indexFile)) { //prototype founded
      prototypeFound = true;
     }
    }
   }